# How to get 0 on failure in new in C++

Tags: c++

If I use `foo = new int [5];` and if allocation fails, an exception is thrown,
My Question is how to handle it or How to get 0 if allocation fails. As well as its is depend on C++ version..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
foo = new(std::nothrow) int[5];
```

It will return `NULL` on error instead of throwing. You may need to add `#include <new>` to get the definition of `std::nothrow`.

About the version dependency, it is quite old, from C++98 I think. If you happen to have an older compiler, say **VisualStudio 6** or **Turbo C**, then probably allocation failure will *always* return `NULL` instead of throwing in the first place, since the `std::bad_alloc` and `std::nothrow` were introduced at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 use the [operator new](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) with `nothrow`

Answer (score 3):

It is typically better to wrap your code in a `try ... catch` and catch the `std::bad_alloc` than to use the "not throwing" form of new `new (std::nothrow) ...` - the main reason for this that while you may be able to control YOUR code, but say you have a class like this:

```
class mine
{
    int x;
    string s;
  public:
    ... some member functions we don't care about here ... 
};
```

and do

```
mine *p = new (std::nothrow) mine;
```

if your system is low on memory, `std::string` may well fail to be allocated, and throw `std::bad_alloc`.

The only exception would be if you KNOW that a particular allocation is very likely to fail, and you have a "fallback", where you allocate smaller size (e.g. for a cache or something). However, this is definitely a bad idea in Linux, since it allows over-commit (that the application allocates more memory than is actually available) - a few weeks ago at work, I was investigating an application that was being killed for "out of memory", and it turns out that on our custom hardware with 2GB of RAM, it allocated until it reached 3GB, and then got killed by the "OOM Killer" because the OS felt starved of memory.

Comment: "Better" depends on the context.  Presumably, he needs to handle the lack of memory locally.  (A typical example of this is enlarging the buffer in an editor.  If you can't enlarge it, you have to spill to disk.)

Comment: Yes, of course, it's not a all or nothing. The main reason I'm suggesting it's better is that you have to be VERY careful what object you are doing this with. POD fine, anything that allocates in the constructor most likely won't work.

Comment: Agreed.  Using no throw new is for very special cases only (and probably only in applications which don't use any of the standard containers).